# Animate position with only CSS

Tags: css

I have the following style on hover:

```
li:hover a {
    left: 65px;
}
```

I know I can animate this with jQuery, but can it be animated with CSS3 alone?

This did **not** work:

```
li:hover a {
    left: 65px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: How exactly does it "not work?" What is the default `left` value, and is `position:absolute` present?

Comment: what is it suppose to do? Change left margine or opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this css:

```
li:hover { 

    left: 0px;

}

li:hover a {

    left: 65px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set position if you want to use 'left' otherwise use 'margin-left'

here is an example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/3gTp6/)